# How to decrypt String in mysql by Selecting?

Tags: php, mysql, encryption

2 fields in my table are encrypted (**email, name**) and the other not.

I use the function **$email = decrypt('email');** to get the original String.

How to use the function into mysql?

the question: how can I insert this function : **decrypt('email')** into this query below ? :

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "select 'name', 'tel', 'adress', 'email' from users where id = 10");
```

**for Encrypting works :**

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `tel`, `adress` , `email`) VALUES (encrypt($name),$tel, $adress, encrypt($email));
```

Comment: can you write the link  pl

Comment: **I found a solution like below :**
`$data_crypted = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);`

`$data_crypted['email'] = decrypt($data_crypted['email']);`

`echo json_encode($data_crypted);`